# Middleman Slim Partial Locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang, middleman

For example, I have a project in Middleman with slim and structure like this:

My main page contains module 'sidebar', which contains module 'newsList', which contains a title. So I try to do smthin like this( it doesn't work ):

On my home page:

```
   = partial 'sidebar', :locals => { list_title: "News" }
```

In 'sidebar':

```
    = partial 'newsList'
```

In 'newsList' I have a title:

```
    h2 = list_title
```

So I want to pass a variable on the main page and display it throw module 'sidebar' in the module 'newsList'. Mb code above is silly, I'm new yet, but I hope you understand what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just toss the variable around:

```
= partial 'newsList', :locals => { list_title: "News" }
```

Comment: it says `undefined local variable or method 'list_title'` when I use it in my slim like so: `a(href='#' class='#{list_title}')`

Comment: @vsync, I've just tried it and it work perfectly fine.